# Function exists but "undefined". Considered as true when used in condition

Tags: javascript, function

Can someone explain to me what is happening in the following code? Thanks.

```js
let myObject = {
    myFunction() {
        console.log('HELLO WORLD');
    }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject.myFunction));

if (myObject.myFunction) {
    console.log('myFunction exists');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described over in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), `JSON.stringify` returns `undefined` when a function is passed as an argument:

> undefined, Functions, and Symbols are not valid JSON values. If any
> such values are encountered during conversion they are either omitted
> (when found in an object) or changed to null (when found in an array).
> JSON.stringify() can return undefined when passing in "pure" values
> like JSON.stringify(function(){}) or JSON.stringify(undefined).

Answer (score 2):

Because JSON.stringify() cannot be used on functions, they are treated as `undefined`. See the explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description).